error: package org.springframework.boot does not exist. However, I do have it in my pom.xml file. Any advice? I'm using VSCode. ^
I'm getting errors when I run a trial setup of a Spring Boot application in VSCode with Maven.
[Running] cd "/Users/shell/Downloads/try/src/main/java/com/example/demo/" && javac TryApplication.java && java TryApplication
TryApplication.java:3: error: package org.springframework.boot does not exist
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
                               ^
TryApplication.java:4: error: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure does not exist
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
                                             ^
TryApplication.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
@SpringBootApplication
 ^
  symbol: class SpringBootApplication
TryApplication.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        SpringApplication.run(TryApplication.class, args);
        ^
  symbol:   variable SpringApplication
  location: class TryApplication
4 errors

This is my pom.xml file showing that I have the org.springframework.boot dependency installed.   I set up everything with Spring Initializr
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.try</groupId>
    <artifactId>try</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>try</name>
    <description>try</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

I checked see if the dependency was installed in the pom.xml file.  I deleted the original file and ran Initializr again, checking that everything was added correctly and all the dependencies are there, but I still get this error even though the dependency was in the pom.xml file again.

Use maven to run not plain java. As you are only compiling the class without adding anything to the classpath.
